# Preventing TempoCache from messing up tempo

Tags: java, javax.sound.midi

I'm using a copy-paste of TempoCache from `javax.sound.midi` to handle the tick calculations for my MIDI player, but on some files the tempo is terribly miscalculated. It seems to average the tempo from the tempo events, but I can't figure out any way to make it better.

The affected file is here: https://github.com/TechShroom/MidiShapesEL/blob/master/src/com/k/midishapes/midi/MidiUtils.java

If anything else is required, I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it happens to be my use of tick2Microsecond which doesn't account for tempo changes and doesn't work for SMPTE timing. Whoops.